# How to add 0 before decimal

Tags: java

I want to add zero before decimal, if the number starts with decimal itself.

Input: .2345
Output: 0.2345

I'm using `DecimalForamtter`. I'm avoiding using string appender.

Please suggest.

Thank You

Comment: format it into a String.

Answer (score 2):

that should give you the expected output:

```
@Test
public void testFloatLeadingZero(){
  float value = .1221313F;
  DecimalFormat lFormatter = new DecimalFormat("##0.0000");
  String lOutput = lFormatter.format(value);
  Assert.assertTrue(lOutput.startsWith("0."));
}
```

or with `String.format`:

```
  @Test
  public void testFloatLeadingZero(){
    float value = .1221313F;
    String lOutput = String.format("%.20f", value);
    Assert.assertTrue(lOutput.startsWith("0."));
    double value2 = .1221313d;
    String lOutput2 = String.format("%.20d", value2);
    Assert.assertTrue(lOutput2.startsWith("0."));
  }
```

I think you are using `Float` right? Otherwise you have to replace `f` with `d` for `Double`.

Comment: It is giving `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many percent/per mille characters in pattern "%.4f%n"`

Comment: Will this approach limit the number of digits after decimal? Because if it will then sorry I'll not be able to use it in my case, as i need to keep that intact.

Comment: I thought you need 4 digits after the seperator. ok then I think String.format is better.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below code and worked in all scenarios. I wanted to get 10 digits including 2 decimal places. It will give me trailing 0s in decimal place also.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00000000.00");
double d1 = 678.90;
System.out.println(df.format(d1));
```

**Output:** 00000678.90